# onTouch event in achartengine seems to be dephased

Tags: android, achartengine

I made a simple chart and added an onTouchListener like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (mGraphPopup.isShowing()) {
            //close popup window
        } else {
            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
            if (seriesSelection != null) {
              // open popupwindow
            }
        }
    return false;
}
```

And I expected perform like this:

1) tap on the chart point - show popup

2) tap again everywhere - close popup

but what is really happening:

1*) tap on a chart point: nothing happens - because seriesSelection is null

2*) tap again far from any chart point - seriesSelection is valid and loads the data of the point clicked on step 1*)

it looks like the chart is late with one touch event.

I even tried to call getCurrentSeriesAndPoint() twice :D but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have meet this problem too recently,and i have find a solution to solve it.Maybe you had solved the problem, I also answer it to help others who meet the problem in the future.Here is the solution:

```
       paintBarView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            paintBarView.onTouchEvent(event);
```

This is code is  important `paintBarView.onTouchEvent(event);  this code is to make sure the view get your input,and you also can solve it like this :

```
try {
                                Field fieldX = paintBarView.getClass().getDeclaredField("oldX");
                                Field fieldY = paintBarView.getClass().getDeclaredField("oldY");
                                fieldX.setAccessible(true);
                                fieldY.setAccessible(true);
                                fieldX.set(paintBarView, event.getX());
                                fieldY.set(paintBarView, event.getY());
                            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            SeriesSelection ss  =   paintBarView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
```

this two solution to solve it,hope can help others

Answer (score 0):

In order to listen for events on your chart and retrieve clicked information, I suggest you do a `setOnClickListener` on your `chartView`. A good example is [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java).

Comment: Dan, setOnClickListener  I've done that but in that way I couldn't find the real coordinates of the event.